# .htaccess Multiple directories load the same page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the follow php files:

```
www/
  -prueba.php
  -prueba-verificador.php
  -contenido.php
```

and the follow .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /quimica/404.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]*)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]*)/([0-9A-Za-z]*)/$ $1-$2.php
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]*)/([0-9A-Za-z]*)/([0-9A-Za-z]*)/$ $1-$2.php/$3
```

when I access to **site.com/prueba/** or **site.com/contenido/** works fine, load prueba.php and contenido.php but when I access to **site.com/prueba/verificador/** load prueba.php instead of prueba-verificador.php

How I can fix this?

Comment: Well first off you don't really need to do `[0-9A-Za-z]*` when you can simply do `\w*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to disable MultiViews:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

The [Apache docs on mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html), describes what the Multiviews Option does, when enabled:

> If the
>   server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not
>   exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named
>   foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those
>   files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it
>   would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then
>   chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that
>   document.